# segmentation fault when I launch ubuntu-emulator

Tags: ubuntu-emulator

I have created an instance of ubuntu-touch with QtCreator (Ubuntu utopic armhf in stable version).

When I start it via command line, I had this error :

```
➜  ~  ubuntu-emulator run utopic         
emulator: autoconfig: -datadir /home/morgan/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/utopic
emulator: Found target ABI=armeabi-v7a, architecture=arm
emulator: Found target API level: 19
emulator: using core hw config path: /home/morgan/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/utopic/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: keyset loaded from: /home/morgan/.android/default.keyset
emulator: trying to load skin file '/usr/share/ubuntu-emulator/skins/EDGE/layout'
emulator: skin network speed: 'full'
emulator: skin network delay: 'none'
emulator: Using initial system image: /home/morgan/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/utopic/system.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /home/morgan/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/utopic/userdata.img
emulator: WARNING: no Real SD Card found at '/home/morgan/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/utopic/sdcardprime.img'
emulator: Physical RAM size: 512MB

emulator: Found target ABI=armeabi-v7a
emulator: Auto-config: -qemu -cpu cortex-a8
Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = arm
  hw.cpu.model = cortex-a8
  hw.ramSize = 512
  hw.screen = touch
  hw.mainKeys = yes
  hw.trackBall = yes
  hw.keyboard = no
  hw.keyboard.lid = no
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = yes
  hw.gsmModem = yes
  hw.gps = yes
  hw.battery = yes
  hw.accelerometer = yes
  hw.audioInput = yes
  hw.audioOutput = yes
  hw.sdCard = yes
  hw.sdCard.path = /home/morgan/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/utopic/sdcard.img
  hw.sdCardPrime = yes
  disk.cachePartition = yes
  disk.cachePartition.path = /home/morgan/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/utopic/cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  hw.lcd.width = 480
  hw.lcd.height = 800
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 160
  hw.lcd.backlight = yes
  hw.gpu.enabled = yes
  hw.camera.back = emulated
  hw.camera.front = none
  vm.heapSize = 48
  hw.sensors.proximity = yes
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = yes
  hw.sensors.orientation = yes
  hw.sensors.temperature = yes
  hw.useext4 = yes
  hw.bluetooth = yes
  kernel.path = /home/morgan/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/utopic/ubuntu-kernel
  disk.ramdisk.path = /home/morgan/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/utopic/ramdisk.img
  disk.systemPartition.initPath = /home/morgan/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/utopic/system.img
  disk.systemPartition.size = 200m
  disk.dataPartition.path = /home/morgan/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/utopic/userdata.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 200m
  avd.name = <build>
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "/usr/share/android/emulator/out/host/linux-x86/bin/emulator-arm"
emulator: argv[01] = "-show-kernel"
emulator: argv[02] = "-cpu"
emulator: argv[03] = "cortex-a9"
emulator: argv[04] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[05] = "/home/morgan/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/utopic/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 /usr/share/android/emulator/out/host/linux-x86/bin/emulator-arm -show-kernel -cpu cortex-a9 -android-hw /home/morgan/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/utopic/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0xc800000,initfile=/home/morgan/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/utopic/system.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: mapping 'system' NAND image to /tmp/android-morgan/emulator-AsBSfL
emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0xc800000,file=/home/morgan/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/utopic/userdata.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '48m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '160'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '1'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'back'
emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000,file=/home/morgan/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/utopic/cache.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
signal: segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

EDIT : I had read somewhere that this bug was caused by `libOpenglRender.so` but after renaming `/usr/share/android/emulator/out/host/linux-x86/lib/libOpenglRender.so` to `/usr/share/android/emulator/out/host/linux-x86/lib/libOpenglRender.so.xx` 
the emulator start but it steel blackscreen, even after 10 minutes of booting

If it can help you, this is the Qt log when I try to start it

```
Waiting for emulator tool to come up..
Waiting for emulator tool to come up..
emulator-5554

Waiting for device to come up..
DevUnLocked
Unity8 is up with PID: initctl: unable to determine sessions 
initctl: unable to determine sessions 

Check device image version..
initctl: unable to determine sessions 
initctl: unable to determine sessions 
chroot: cannot change root directory to /data/ubuntu: No such file or directory 
initctl: unable to determine sessions 
initctl: unable to determine sessions 
chroot: cannot change root directory to /data/ubuntu: No such file or directory 
initctl: unable to determine sessions
initctl: unable to determine sessions
chroot: cannot change root directory to /data/ubuntu: No such file or directory
initctl: unable to determine sessions 
initctl: unable to determine sessions 
chroot: cannot change root directory to /data/ubuntu: No such file or directory 
initctl: unable to determine sessions 
initctl: unable to determine sessions 

Check if the device is connected to a network..
1

Detecting if openssh-server is installed..
..openssh-server was not installed.
Is device image read-only or writable..
1

..read-only image.
Are developer tools installed..
0

..developer tools are not installed.
Installing openssh-server..
initctl: unable to determine sessions 
initctl: unable to determine sessions 
chroot: cannot change root directory to /data/ubuntu: No such file or directory 
initctl: unable to determine sessions 
initctl: unable to determine sessions 
chroot: cannot change root directory to /data/ubuntu: No such file or directory 
initctl: unable to determine sessions 
initctl: unable to determine sessions 
chroot: cannot change root directory to /data/ubuntu: No such file or directory 

..openssh-server was installed.
Detecting if openssh-server is installed..
..openssh-server was not installed.
Is device image read-only or writable..
1

..read-only image.
Are developer tools installed..
0

..developer tools are not installed.
Waiting for emulator tool to come up..
```

I really don't understand what's going on !

Comment: i have got the same problem when I go to the emulator